How to correct implement white labelling with NextJS?
I need to create a project of multiple website using the same NextJS app but with a different backend and a different theme. For the backend it's quite easy since I just use process.env at building time to get different connection.
But I struggle regarding the theme.
The project is structured with mono repo like this:
- apps/
   - website-1/
      - src/
         - app/ 
            - [[...route]]/
               - page.tsx
   - website-2/
- packages/
   - generic-frontend/
      - src/
         - app/ 
            - [[...route]]/
               - page.tsx


The content page.tsx of the library looks like this:
export default async function Page({ params, searchParams }: PageProps) {

});

And the page.tsx of website-1 and website-2 like this:
import Page from 'generic-frontend/[[...route]]/page';

export default Page;

Now the ugly part, I pass the theme inside apps/website-1/src/app/[[...route]]/layout.tsx like this:
import { theme } from '../theme';
global.theme = theme;

I know it's not good but until now it was working. If I update NextJS from 14.1.4 to 14.2.0 it does not work anymore.
The theme is needed at building time in server component and probably the update of NextJS changes the way things are loaded. Now global.theme is undefined when I need it.
Also note that sometimes the theme is used directly in the component under the imports like this:
import { CSSProperties } from 'react';
import { getTheme } from '@/themes';

const theme = getTheme();

export default function Button() {
 ...
}

I can't use context since the theme is needed server side.
So my question is, how should I implement this pattern the right way in NextJS?
